# Revalidate and Repaint not Working

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jframe

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Class4 {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void mainMethod(int event){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Love Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(500,200);     
        f.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        if(event == 0){




            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            p.setBounds(150, 0, 500, 75);
            p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,75));
            JTextField boy = new JTextField();
            boy.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,40));
            JTextField girl = new JTextField();
            girl.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,40));
            p.add(boy);
            p.add(girl);
            gbc.insets = new Insets(-90,310,0,0);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            f.add(p,gbc);

            JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            p3.setBounds(0, 0, 150, 75);
            p3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,75));
            Class5 c5o = new Class5();
            c5o.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,75));
            p3.add(c5o);
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0,0,90,330);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            f.add(p3,gbc);

            JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            Class7 c7o = new Class7();
            p2.add(c7o);
            p2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,40));
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0,0,-20,0);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            f.add(p2,gbc);

            f.setVisible(true);

            //1st
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,f.isVisible());


        }

        if(event == 5){

            JPanel p4 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            p4.setBounds(0,140,500,55);
            Class2 c2o = new Class2();
            Dimension d2 = new Dimension(500,55);
            c2o.setPreferredSize(d2);
            p4.setPreferredSize(d2);
            p4.add(c2o);
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0,0,-130,0);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;  
            f.add(p4,gbc);

            f.invalidate();
            f.validate();
            f.repaint();

            //2nd
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,f.isVisible());
        }

    }

}
```

The revalidate and repaint doesn't work. I have an layout manager, so I suspect the problem is with the if statements. The 1st time I test the visibility of f, it returned true. The second time I tested the same thing, it returned false. Why doesn't my revalidate and repaint work? How I need to do to get it to work?

Comment: `The revalidate and repaint doesn't work.` - your code isn't using revalidate().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some issues with this code, but the major one is the scope of your `JFrame` reference `f`.

Assumed that you are calling the method somehow like in this `main` sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Class4 c = new Class4();
  c.mainMethod(0);
  c.mainMethod(5);
}
```

Then, your code is creating a second `JFrame` during the second call.

Move the JFrame creation into the constructor and make `f` a member variable:

```
public class Class4 {

    private JFrame f;

    public Class4() {
       f = new JFrame("Love Test");
       f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       f.setSize(500,200);     
       f.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    }

    // ...
}
```

You can then modify the JFrame in subsequent calls of the `mainMethod()`.

Some additional notes:

- [Avoid reusing GridBagConstraints](http://www.coderanch.com/t/436788/GUI/java/Reuse-GridBagConstraints). Create them through the constructor. This makes the code much more robust.
- You do not need to get the `contentPane` from the `JFrame` anymore (as suggested in an other answer). As of Java 1.5, the `add()` methods of `JFrame` directly delegate to the content pane.
- There is no need to do `invalidate()` or `repaint()` when adding components to the `JFrame`. `add()` already invalidates the component hierarchy. However, you need to call `validate()` when the component has already been shown (as in your case). See [java.awt.Container.add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29) for more information.

Comment: what is a member variable? @Andreas

Comment: A class member is an attribute (or a method) which is bound to the class. I have updated my answer to make it clearer. Your reference `f` is local to your `mainMethod()` and therefore goes out of scope when the method finishes.

Comment: I can't use a constructor in Class4 as I have other classes needing to create the object for the class. This will cause the whole program to be messed up.  @Andreas

Comment: I do not understand this - You should be able to add a constructor in any case. Even if the object is created from a completely different class in a completely different package, the constructor is executed when the object is created. Even if you do not specify your own constructor, a default constructor is created, so there is already one. Class4 also does **not** extend any class which could prevent (through its own private constructor) to add one

Answer (score 3):

```
 if(event == 5){

        JPanel p4 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p4.setBounds(0,140,500,55);
        Class2 c2o = new Class2();
        Dimension d2 = new Dimension(500,55);
        c2o.setPreferredSize(d2);
        p4.setPreferredSize(d2);
        p4.add(c2o);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0,0,-130,0);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;  
        f.add(p4,gbc);

        f.invalidate();
        f.validate();
        f.repaint();

        //2nd
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,f.isVisible());
    }
```

The frame `f` it isn't visible(missing the `f.setVisible(true);` ), so not need to be revalidated and repainted in this case, it will not be visible for user.
Also use a logger or a breakpoint to test `f.isVisible()` because that will block the ui.

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand your answer... @matheszabi

Comment: thats the problem! -add a f.setVisible(true); before JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,f.isVisible());

Comment: It is visible, but making it visible is not the primary aim. My aim is to refresh the JFrame. @matheszabi

Comment: based on that code, what you have provided it isn't visible! show me where can be visible, or update code

Answer (score 2):

I'm having trouble seeing exactly what you're looking for. An SSCCE would really help. Is this what you're looking for?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Canv extends JComponent {

    GridBagConstraints gbc;

    public Canv (int event) {

        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        switch(event)
        {
            case 0:
                this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
                this.setBounds(150, 0, 500, 75);
                this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,75));
                JTextField boy = new JTextField();
                boy.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,40));
                JTextField girl = new JTextField();
                girl.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,40));
                this.add(boy);
                this.add(girl);
                gbc.insets = new Insets(-90,310,0,0);
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy = 0;
                this.add(this,gbc);

                JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                p3.setBounds(0, 0, 150, 75);
                p3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,75));
                //Class5 c5o = new Class5();
                //c5o.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,75));
                //p3.add(c5o);
                gbc.insets = new Insets(0,0,90,330);
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy = 0;
                this.add(p3,gbc);

                JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
                //Class7 c7o = new Class7();
                //p2.add(c7o);
                p2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,40));
                gbc.insets = new Insets(0,0,-20,0);
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy = 0;
                this.add(p2,gbc);
                break;
            case 5:
                JPanel p4 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                p4.setBounds(0,140,500,55);
                //Class2 c2o = new Class2();
                Dimension d2 = new Dimension(500,55);
                //c2o.setPreferredSize(d2);
                p4.setPreferredSize(d2);
                //p4.add(c2o);
                gbc.insets = new Insets(0,0,-130,0);
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy = 0;  
                this.add(p4,gbc);

                //this.invalidate();
                this.validate();
                this.repaint();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,this.isVisible());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(){

    }


}

public class Class4 {

    static int event;
    static JFrame frame;
    static Canv canvas;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Love Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,200);     
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        //event = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        event = 5;
        canvas = new Canv(event);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Running the above code would return true in the dialog box. In order to change between events, just add another method in Class4 to reset Canv, by calling its constructor with a different event number.